# Kendo Grid static columns search in chrome broken

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a problem, where I have a Kendo grid, with static columns and when user searches the page with CTRL+F, then only the static columns will be scrolled down and not the content.

For example:
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/frozen-columns

When searching for a ship name `Magazzini` with ctrl+F on the page, you can see that the frozen columns will scroll down, while the content in the left does not change.

This results in a display of invalid data, for example a row:

```
 10275  Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti Austria    Graz    Kirchgasse 6
```

While in reality it should be:

```
 10275  Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti Italy  Bergamo Via Ludovico il Moro 22
```

This happens in Google chrome, while in Firefox, it does show that it found 1 result, but does not scroll to that result.

I think this behaviour is not intended and any suggestions how to fix it?

Comment: Is disabling Ctrl+F for the grid an option for you? I was thinking you could create a custom search widget just for searching items from your grid then using a plugin like [disableFind.js](https://github.com/seangransee/Disable-CTRL-F-jQuery-plugin) to disable Ctrl+F on your grid completely.